# In MVC, how can I make this example of a checkbox checked by default?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, default, checked

I am trying to make a checkbox in MVC be checked by default.

Below is my code.  For all examples I have seen of this, the person uses something different than what I am trying so I have not been able to find help on this yet.

```
<%=Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Delete)%>
```

I have tried adding the `, new { @checked = "checked" }` approach and that didnt work. I got a squiggly line under the first "{".... the entire line looked like this...

```
<%=Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Delete, new { @checked = "checked" }))%>
```

Any advice on how I can get this checkbox to be auto checked?

thanks for any help group.

Will

This is what I am using in my controller. This is the start of the COntroler... this is not work. FirstNameAsBusiness is the name of the checkbox

In the view...

<%=Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.FirstNameAsBusiness)%> 
<%=Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.FirstNameAsBusiness)%>

In the controller....

```
Function Edit(ByVal a As AuditModel) As ActionResult
    a.FirstNameAsBusiness = True 
    Return View(a)
End Function
```

Comment: What language do you think you're writing?

Comment: I am trying to use VB not C#.  I am new to MVC and am trying to learn.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

Comment: typo? You have an extra parenthesis at the end of your line.

Comment: He's trying to use VB, but his code is in C# `new { @checked = "checked" }`

Comment: I didnt know new { @checked = "checked" } was C#... like i said, i am learning.

Comment: It's all good. We're all learning. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
<%=Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Delete, New With { .checked = "checked" })%>
```

The only other thing I can think of is to do as SLaks has suggested.

```
Function Edit(ByVal a As AuditModel) As ActionResult
    a.FirstNameAsBusiness = True 
    a.Delete = True ''# This should do it.
    Return View(a)
End Function
```

View

```
<%=Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Delete)%>
```

Comment: Stupid question but where do I save the Function?

Comment: That function belongs in your Controller ( **M** odel **V** iew **C** ontroller) You have to have a Model already... (model.Delete). You're controller will send the model to the view, but first you have to set the Delete property).

Comment: Also where is Index even called?  I already have a function in my Controller called Index.

Comment: Index is just an example. What is the name of your view.  If you're view name is "Edit", then the function will be `Function Edit() As ActionResult`. Whatever the name of your View, you ALREADY have that in your Controller, because you wouldn't be able to see your view otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `model.Delete` to true.

**EDIT**: You need to set it before calling `Checkbox`.

Comment: That didnt work.... I tried...                                     <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.Delete)%>
                                    <% Model.Delete = true %>
                                    <%=Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Delete)%>

Comment: @Lee: If you set it to true after writing the Checkbox, the Checkbox will not magically change.

Comment: Before calling `CheckBoxFor`.  Proper design would be to set it in the controller or model.

Comment: You don't want to do it "before" inside your view. You want to send it from the controller (which runs before the view). And going a little more advanced, you could consider initializing a ViewModel that has the properties you need from the Controller, then pass that ViewModel to the View.

Comment: I FINALLY got it to work. Apparently there are two functions called Edit. One for when the page gets loaded and another when a submit buttin gets clicked on the page.  I was using the wrong Edit function. When setting it to TRUE in the "pre" edit page it works. Thanks Rockinthesixstring for the help....

Answer (score -1):

You could always just set the 'Delete' property to true on the constructor of your model (therefore the default value).

Very similar to what has been suggested above but this way no matter where you use the 'Delete' property it will always be ticked by default.

It all depends on if this is classed as business logic or more a View specific decision.